# Работа скрипта с подгружаемым контентом

Tags: jquery, javascript

С помощью .replaceWith заменил один блок другим, в котором есть кликабельный элемент. Теперь по клику нужно вызвать Action. Скрипт не видит мой элемент. Буду рад любой подсказке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

любая подсказка: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Дело в том, что на момент, когда вы навешивали обработчик на клик, подгруженного элемента ещё не было.
Но метод on() не только назначает обработчик, а ещё и следит, не появилось ли новых элементов, на которые тоже стоит назначить такой же обработчик.

Comment: Спасибо за скорый ответ! В упор не вижу ошибку. Вроде бы должно быть так:
$('#button').click(function () {

            $.get('@Url.Action("GetNewDiv","Home", new { id = Model.ID } )', function (data) { 
                $('.divToReplace').replaceWith(data);
            });

            $('#newButton').on('click', function () {
                alert("Clicked!");
            });
        });
Но работать не хочет.

Comment: справедливо не хочет. У вас уже есть элемент с таким id на странице — это раз. .on не будет следить за самим #newButton — это два. На момент запуска слежения же ещё не было того контекста, в котором нужно отслеживать. Применять надо как-то так: $('body').on('click', '#newButton', function(){alert('clicked!')})

но конечно лучше не body, а какой-то более суженный контекст.

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь все отлично.